# RecyclerView with another RecyclerView of images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm using a `recyclerview` to create my components but each component has a button to take or pick a photo, so I need to add photos in this inner `recyclerview`. But when I do this doest add in the right place and need to add more of 2 photos to show appear on the list. I follow this code to do this [code exemple](https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-a-vertical-recyclerview/), When I debug I see that it is inserting right but not appearing right

my adapter of external recyclerview:

```
public class ItemsCategoryInstallationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder>{

private ArrayList<ItemsInstallation> arrayList;
private SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();
private int positionArray;
private ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder holder;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences preferencesItem;
private ArrayAdapter<Integer> quantityAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> coletorAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> content_RFID = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> content_RElE = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> content_COLETOR = new ArrayList<>();
private int codigo = 0;
private ClickListenerPhoto clickHandler;

public ItemsCategoryInstallationAdapter(ArrayList<ItemsInstallation> data, ClickListenerPhoto clickListenerPhoto){

    this.clickHandler = clickListenerPhoto;

    if (data != null)
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(data);
    else arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewholder_itemscategoryinstallation, parent, false);
    return new ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  final ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.cb_checkItem.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNome());
    holder.btn_dropInstallation.setRotation(expandState.get(position) ? 180f : 0f);
    positionArray = position;
    preferences = holder.et_number.getContext().getSharedPreferences("Check", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferencesItem = holder.et_number.getContext().getSharedPreferences("ITEM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    holder.clickHandler = this.clickHandler;
    this.holder = holder;
    final boolean alterado = false;
    holder.imageGridAdapter.setData(arrayList.get(position).getArrayPhotos());
    holder.imageGridAdapter.setRowIndex(position);

    holder.btn_addPicItemInst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickHandler != null) {
                clickHandler.takePictureButton(view, position);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.btn_getPicItemInst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickHandler != null) {
                clickHandler.pickPictureButton(view, position);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Hide elements that will not be used
     */

    if(arrayList.get(position).getCod() == 0){ //coletor
        holder.ll_quantityUsed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_type.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_frequency.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_number.getText();
        getItens(3);
        codigo = 0;
    }else if (arrayList.get(position).getCod() == 1){ // sondas
        holder.ll_type.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_frequency.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_model.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_chipNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        callQuantity();
    }else if(arrayList.get(position).getCod() == 2){ //RFID
        holder.ll_quantityUsed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_type.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_chipNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_frequency.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getItens(2);
        codigo = 2;
    }else if (arrayList.get(position).getCod() == 4){ //relé
        holder.ll_quantityUsed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_type.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_chipNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_frequency.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getItens(4);
        codigo = 4;
    }else if (arrayList.get(position).getCod() == 8){ //lacres do cabo de sonda
        holder.ll_type.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_frequency.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_chipNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_model.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        callQuantity();
    }else {
        holder.ll_quantityUsed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_type.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_frequency.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ll_model.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_chipNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.et_number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * Expand card on click
     */
    holder.btn_dropInstallation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        }
    });
}    
public void insertPhoto(Photo photo){
    holder.imageGridAdapter.insertItem(photo);
}

/**
 * Get array size
 * @return
 */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

/**
 * get item id
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position).getCod();
}

/**
 * get the type of view
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

/**
 * Insert item method
 * @param user
 */
private void insertItem(ItemsInstallation user) {
    arrayList.add(user);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
}
/**
 * Update Method
 * @param position
 */
public void updateItem(int position, Photo photo) {

    holder.imageGridAdapter.insertItem(photo);

    Log.e("Qnt", arrayList.get(position).getArrayPhotos().size() + " tamanho - " + position +" Posicao" );
    //  userModel.incrementAge();
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

/**
 * Remove item method
 * @param position
 */
private void removerItem(int position) {
    arrayList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, arrayList.size());
}
```

}

```
public class ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public ImageButton btn_dropInstallation;
public Button btn_addPicItemInst;
public Button btn_getPicItemInst;
public LinearLayout expandableLayout;
public CheckBox cb_checkItem;
public CardView cardView;
public Spinner sp_frequency;
public Spinner sp_type;
public Spinner sp_model;
public Spinner sp_quantityUsed;
public EditText et_chipNumber;
public EditText et_number;
public LinearLayout ll_frequency;
public LinearLayout ll_type;
public LinearLayout ll_model;
public LinearLayout ll_quantityUsed;
public ClickListenerPhoto clickHandler;
public RecyclerView rv_photosItemsInstallation;
public ImageGridAdapter imageGridAdapter;


public ItemsCategoryInstallationHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cb_checkItem = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_checkItem);
    Context context = itemView.getContext();
    rv_photosItemsInstallation = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_photosItemsInstallation);
    rv_photosItemsInstallation.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    imageGridAdapter = new ImageGridAdapter();
    rv_photosItemsInstallation.setAdapter(imageGridAdapter);

    btn_dropInstallation = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dropInstallation);
    btn_addPicItemInst = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_addPicItemInst);
    btn_getPicItemInst = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_getPicItemInst);

    expandableLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
    cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

    sp_frequency = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_frequency);
    sp_type = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_type);
    sp_model = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_model);
    sp_quantityUsed = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_quantityUsed);

    et_chipNumber =(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.et_chipNumber);
    et_number =(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.et_number);

    ll_frequency = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_frequency);
    ll_type = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_type);
    ll_model = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_model);
    ll_quantityUsed = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_quantityUsed);
}
```

}

my inner recycleview:

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageGridHolder>{

private ArrayList<Photo> photos;
private int mRowIndex = -1;

public ImageGridAdapter(){}

public void setRowIndex(int index) {
    mRowIndex = index;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Photo> data) {
    if (photos != data) {
        photos = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageGridHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewholder_itemimage, parent, false);
    return new ImageGridHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageGridHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    try {
        holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(holder.itemImage.getContext().getContentResolver(), photos.get(position).getPathUri()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.itemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.itemImage.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, photos.get(position).getPathUri()));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return photos.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return photos.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void insertItem(Photo photo) {
    photos.add(photo);
    photo.setId(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
}
```

}

```
public class ImageGridHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public ImageView itemImage;

public ImageGridHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
}
```

}

**edit** This code works if you try insert in ther third time

Comment: It might be considered to instead of hiding whole views based on position, you simply do not pass them to Adapter. `RecyclerView` is much easier to work with if it uses all the elements from the list it is passed on.

Comment: How I do this? Hiding the elements in holder class?

Comment: You "filter" them out of List before passing it to Adapter, instead of filtering inside Adapter. Of Course, some things you have to do inside adapter...

Comment: I will try, thanks